# How to target upcoming slide in Caroufredsel before transition when 3 items are visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, slideshow, caroufredsel

So far I've managed to get caroufredsel to add a class to the active slide, but only after the transition has completed. I can't seem to figure out a way to have it add a class to the slide it's about to transition to.

Here's my working example that selects the active slide after transition: http://codepen.io/rsmm/pen/Iwkeg

And here's my failed attempt at getting it to select the slide it's switching to: http://codepen.io/rsmm/pen/xGmFK

It seems to work at first, but quickly gets out of sync.

Most of the difficulties I'm having seem to be due to the fact that 3 items are showing at the same time. I have yet to find a way to access the index of the slideshow.

The documentation is a bit confusing. They seem to have rebranded their site, and shoved the detailed documentation into a folder and branded it as  "old".

In case it helps, here's the most detailed documentation I could find: http://docs.dev7studios.com/caroufredsel-old/configuration.php

Comment: please deliver code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?
replace:

`onAfter : $highlight,`

with:

`onBefore: $highlight,`

and:

`items.filter(":eq(1)").addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");`

with:

`items.filter(":eq(2)").addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");`

You would also need to add `onAfter:someFunc` like so:

`pagination: {
      container: '.carousel-pagination',
deviation: 1,
      onAfter:someFunc //here you would highlight eq(1)
    }`

and here is the source: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/afHGs

Comment: Thank you. This is much much closer to what I want. It appears that it doesn't function correctly if you navigate backwards or use the pagination. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: See the link I have provided, I've made some changes regarding back button and pagination. Please look through the code, try too understand it. And you would be able too finish the code.I wish you luck on your project. May the force be with you :), I think the slider is finished as it is.

Comment: And if you want to unhighlight the current highlighted frame when paginating, you can add the unhighlight part to the switchBlock function.

Comment: Thank you. I will look this over in detail, and figure it out. I really appreciate all your help.